# Is the source code for Silverlight 4 controls available?

Tags: silverlight

I can only find the sources for Silverlight 2:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=EB83ED4C-AC85-4DE9-8395-285628EE2254&displaylang=en

Hasn't Microsoft released the source code since then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the free [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) tool to look at the disassembled source code of any .NET or Silverlight assembly.

[image: Silverlight Button in Reflector]

Also you can download the sources for the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) that additionally contains the source code for the SDK controls like the DataGrid.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of Reflector, but I prefer the source from Microsoft because it contains comments, real variable names and is overall more readable.

Comment: DataGrid source is not in the toolkit